# Foreign key problem when saving data to SQL Server using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

[C# code and database view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sv9UY.png)

Here is my database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE University 
(
    UniversityID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    UniversityName nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (UniversityID)
)

CREATE TABLE Enstitute 
(
    EnstituteID int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    UniversityID int NOT NULL,
    EnstituteName nvarchar(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (EnstituteID),
    FOREIGN KEY (UniversityID) REFERENCES University(UniversityID)
)
```

Part of the Entity Framework code:

```
en.EnstituteName = enstituteBox.Text; //entitute name input
uni.UniversityName = universityBox.Text;  //university name input

db.Enstitute.Add(en);
db.University.Add(uni);
db.SaveChanges();
```

My problem is, when I add data that the user inputs, I write the same university name but in the database records the same university names saved with different UniversityID. 1 enstitute has 1 university and 1 university have more than one enstitute. When I select a university, if the university is selected before, I want save to same UniversityID (foreign key) to Enstitute table, not a new Foreign key ID. Can someone help me?

Comment: You need to set `en.University = existingUniversityObject`.

Comment: I believe in English the spelling is usually `Institute`

Comment: Your title says MySQL but you have tagged SQL Server - which is it? And please don't use images for code - use formatted text.

Comment: i didn't write mysql but admin edited as mysql server. I am new in stackoverflow . I don't know how use . I am learning.

Comment: I do apologise you are correct, someone (not an admin, anyone with enough reputation can edit) edited it incorrectly.

Comment: Can I edit foreign key manually when using Entity Framework. It creates automatically foreignkeyID (1-2-3-4....).
Or should I write a insert query instead of using an entity framework.
I am new started using to entity framework sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood the problem is that you are adding the university even if already exist. Your PK is pointing to the ID, so the name is not part of it. Probably you need to specify a double PK or check if the university name exist already.

Try this

```
var university = await db.University.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x =>x.UniversityName == uni.UniversityName);  

if(university == null){   
    //your code 
}
else 
{   
    en.UniversityId = university.UniversityId;   
    db.Enstitude.Add(en);
}  
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: how can i do like this :
EntituteID, UniversityID ,EntituteName;
     (  1       -        1   -        Name1)
      ( 2       -        1     -      Name2)
So,a university may be associated with more than one institution.
I chose a university, I chose an Institute, but I did not show them like that in the database.

Comment: To declare a double key you should do it manually in the Context's ModelCreation method. Also if the University is already insert, you should not insert it again, but looking for it with a select and then picking up the id and adding the id to the Enstitute new row.

Comment: I edit the comment so you can try that piece of code and seem if it works for you